# I want to remove the header icon in mobile view and only keep the search icon

Tags: shopify

I need assistance with modifying the mobile view of my website. Specifically, I would like to remove the header icon in the mobile view and retain only the search icon. Could you please guide me on how to achieve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhnL3.jpg)

I want to remove the header icon in mobile view and only keep the search icon.

Comment: To remove it from mobile only need knowledge of CSS, so you add the code for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how are you doing it but in Shopify community forums there are a few answers:

1: https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/removing-cart-icon-for-mobile-view/m-p/2118771

2: https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/remove-cart-icon/m-p/2261247

Hope it helps!!